# error creating in .xaml when creating in .xaml.cs backing code works

Tags: xaml, silverlight-5.0, autofac, caliburn.micro

I am having a strange issue where creating my class that derives from Caliburn.Micro.Autofac.AutofacBootstrapper in my App.xaml fails with a build error:

The tag 'Bootstrapper' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:TestProject'

But if I just create the bootstrapper in App.xaml.cs everything works.

The code below shows what I can do to make things work. If I uncomment the Bootstrapper in the App.xaml and comment out the one in the App.xaml.cs I get the build error.

How are the two any different?

Intellisense is happy with the Bootstrapper in the App.xaml I only get the error on build.

Heres is my App.xaml

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestProject"
         x:Class="TestProject.App"
         >
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <!--
                <local:Bootstrapper x:Key="Bootstrapper"/>
                -->
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

and here is my App.xaml.cs

```
namespace TestProject
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {

        public App()
        {
            new Bootstrapper();

            this.UnhandledException += this.Application_UnhandledException;

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            // If the app is running outside of the debugger then report the exception using
            // the browser's exception mechanism. On IE this will display it a yellow alert 
            // icon in the status bar and Firefox will display a script error.
            if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {

                // NOTE: This will allow the application to continue running after an exception has been thrown
                // but not handled. 
                // For production applications this error handling should be replaced with something that will 
                // report the error to the website and stop the application.
                e.Handled = true;
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate { ReportErrorToDOM(e); });
            }
        }

        private void ReportErrorToDOM(ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string errorMsg = e.ExceptionObject.Message + e.ExceptionObject.StackTrace;
                errorMsg = errorMsg.Replace('"', '\'').Replace("\r\n", @"\n");

                System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Eval("throw new Error(\"Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application " + errorMsg + "\");");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and  here is Bootsteapper.cs

```
namespace TestProject
{
    public class Bootstrapper : AutofacBootstrapper<MainPageViewModel>
    {
        public Bootstrapper()
        {
            base.ConfigureBootstrapper();
            EnforceNamespaceConvention = false;
            ViewModelBaseType = typeof(IShell);
        }

        protected override void ConfigureContainer(Autofac.ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<MainPageViewModel>();

            base.ConfigureContainer(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this is weird, i have two things to ask you though, first where did you get AutofacBootstrapper<> from, second the problem might be that the bootstrapper itself might not be compiling correctly ?

Comment: I used NuGet to get the latest version of Caliburn.Micro.Autofac (1.5.0.0) which also pulled in its dependencies Caliburn.Micro (1.4.1.0) and Autofac (2.6.3.862).

Comment: The strange part is it works normally when instanciated from the code behind.  It does seem to be somehow related to Cliburn.Micro instantiating an empty DummyClass from the xaml file works fine.

Comment: It seems like there's something wrong with the nuget package and/or the source project config. I downloaded the code and compiled from the source and the App.xaml worked, but I didn't get any intellisense. I needed to put the .cs files into a new project and compile it myself to fix it all up.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set your bootstrapper beyond the MergedDictionaries?

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:Bootstrapper x:Key="Bootstrapper" />
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Assembly;component/OtherResource.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```